# Bad Operand Types between 2 classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to code this so it can give me a certain discount based on how many points the client has, when i try to compile, i get the bad operand types error, First type: Purchase second type: Double, i can't understand why it doesn't work, because "price" from the class purchase, is a also a double, if you could help me it would help a lot!! Thanks

```
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase price){
    if (points > 2000)
        price = price - (price * 0.05);

}
```

a part of purchase class:

```
public class Purchase{
     private double price;
```

Comment: Can you apply `*` to any reference types?

Comment: Yes you have a `price` inside of `Purchase` which you are not using. You are using the `Purchase` variable named `price`.

Comment: And how i do i use variable price?

Comment: @user3511983 did you downvote my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in you code is that you use an object of `Purchase` called `price`. If you rename the variable to give it a better name, it's easier to see what's wrong here:

```
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase purchase){
    if (points > 2000)
        purchase = purchase - (purchase * 0.05);
}
```

You just can't use `Purchase` objects in a calculation. Note that you also cannot reference `purchase.price` since it is private. Something like this will work:

```
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase purchase){
    if (points > 2000)
        purchase.setPrice(purchase.getPrice() - (purchase.getPrice() * 0.05));
}
```

Using getters and setters is always problematic, especially in a situation like this. It hides your intent behind (unimportant) technical details. In this case, it's better to tell the purchase object what to do. This will show every reader what was the intent of your code:

```
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase purchase){
    if (points > 2000)
        purchase.applyDiscount(0.05);
}

//Part of Purchase.java
public class Purchase {
    //...
    public void applyDiscount(double discountPercent) {
        price = price - (price * discountPercent);
    }
}
```

No you can improve the other names in your code to make your intent even clearer:

```
public static final DISCOUNT_FOR_REPEAT_CUSTOMERS = 0.05;
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase purchase){
    if (customerCanGetDiscount())
        purchase.applyDiscount(DISCOUNT_FOR_REPEAT_CUSTOMERS);
}

private boolean customerCanGetDiscount() {
    return points > 2000;
}
```

The more your code shows your real intent, and the better your names are, the easier it will be to spot bugs like the one you had.

**A final word of warning:** This is not part of the question, but: **Do not use floating point values (float, double) for financial calculations** (unless you **really** know what you are doing). Floating point values are not precise, floating point math shows some surprising behaviors. You do not want this in financial calculations. Have a look at BigDecimal (but also, make sure you know what you are doing before you use it).

Comment: I tryed editing my code so it would be like yours, but then another error showed up at class Client. error: non-static method applyDiscount(double) cannot be referenced from a static context, have i done something wrong?

Comment: @user3511983 It looks like one of your methods is static (and should not be). In my answer, I assumed that all methods would work on some object, none of them would be static. If you code is different to that assumption, you'll have to figure out what needs to be static and what needs to be not (i.e. instance methods).

Answer (score 0):

You named you `Price` variable the same as the `Price` class's instance variable `price` -- confusing.  Your `price` is a `Purchase`, not a `double`, so you can't use `*` on it.  The `price` instance vairable is private, so you can't reference it from outside the class anyway.

Create a method in `Purchase` to adjust the `price` instance variable accordingly.  Then you can call it in `makeAPurchase`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this method is in the Purchase class:

```
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase price){
    if (points > 2000)
        price = price - (price.price * 0.05);
```

}

For better naming, consider changing this to:

```
public void makeAPurchase(Purchase purchase){
    if (points > 2000)
        price = price - (purchase.getPrice() * 0.05);
```

}

Comment: I would love to know why this has been marked down...would the culprit care to explain?

Comment: Absolutely no reason to downvote this - spot the weak programmer who can't back up his/her opinion on something...